# How to print value with dynamic variable

Tags: twig

**datas**

```
$datas = [
    'first' => [
        1 => [
            'count' => 20
        ],
        2 => [
            'count' => 100
        ]
    ]
];
```

I have another data load from database, the result is like:

```
$rows = [
    1 => 'aaaa',
    2 => 'bbbb'
];
```

I loop the rows in view

```
{% for key, row in rows %}
    {{ datas.first.key.count }} // empty
{% endfor %}
```

I want to use rows key to show datas count, but it's not work, datas.first.1.count print the correct result

**In PHP**

```
$datas = [
    'first' => [
        1 => [
            'count' => 20
        ],
        2 => [
            'count' => 100
        ]
    ]
];

$rows = [
    1 => 'aaaa',
    2 => 'bbbb'
];

foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
    echo 'count is :'.$datas['first'][$key]['count'];
}
```

This is the sample on PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think (not very clear) you want to do this:

```
{% for row in datas.first %}
    {{ row.count }} // count value
{% endfor %}
```

Here is a working twigfiddle:

https://twigfiddle.com/6yup1l

Comment: thanks for your answer but It's not dynamic, I put an example to the article

Comment: I'm not certain what part you mean is dynamic? In Twig you can use an [IF statement](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html), then check if your array contains `first` and then do something. Your second example just shows `$rows` with keys of `1` and `2`.

Comment: the key is dynamic, this sample only two datas, in real world maybe over 30 datas, I can't use if statement

Comment: Just use the array notation in `twig` and you are good to go e.g. `{% set index = 42 %}{{ data['first'][index]['count'] }}`

Comment: I found the answer, {{ attribute(data.first, key).count }}